# Issue with the join expression in Access 2013

Tags: t-sql, ms-access, ms-access-2013

Given below is the sample of my code. When I tried to switch to the design view it gives me an error:

> "Microsoft Access can't represent the join expression a.Course_name=b.Course_name in Design view".

When I searched this error on stackoverflow I found one post. According to the post the solution is given in this link (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/207868). According to this link, `try to remove extra parenthesis (especially nested parenthesis) and problem will be resolved`. However, in my query I don't have nested parenthesis. So I don't know how to fix it. Any help would be appreciated.

```
SELECT a.Course_name, COUNT(b.Student_code) AS [Total], Format(b.Retrieved_date,"mmmm yyyy") AS [Month]
FROM Course AS a LEFT JOIN (SELECT b.Course_name, b.Student_code, b.Retrieved_date FROM pending-enrolment AS b WHERE b.Retrieved_date BETWEEN [Forms]![ParameterForm]![txtBeginDate] AND [Forms]![ParameterForm]![txtEndDate]) b
ON a.Course_name=b.Course_name
GROUP BY a.Course_name, b.Retrieved_date
;
```

Comment: What happens if you bracket the table name which includes a hyphen like this? `[pending-enrolment]`

Comment: @HansUp Awesome. It worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code (tested and works 100%):

```
SELECT Course.Course_name, Count(b.Student_code) AS CountOfStudent_code,
    Format([b].[Retrieved_date],"mmmm yyyy") AS [Month]
FROM Course
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT [pending-enrolment].Course_name, [pending-enrolment].Student_code,
        [pending-enrolment].Retrieved_date
    FROM [pending-enrolment]
    WHERE ([pending-enrolment].Retrieved_date
    Between [Forms]![ParameterForm]![txtBeginDate]
    And [Forms]![ParameterForm]![txtEndDate])
) AS b ON Course.Course_name = b.Course_name
GROUP BY Course.Course_name, Format([b].[Retrieved_date],"mmmm yyyy");
```